# Issue with Side-effects - LaunchedEffect and SideEffect in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Why SideEffect gets called ever-time my composable is invalidated , but same does-not hold true for LaunchedEffect?

```
sealed class SomeState {
 object Error:SomeState()
 data class Content(): SomeState
}

class MyViewModel:ViewModel {
  internal val response: MutableLiveData<SomeState> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<SomeState>()
  }
}

// This is top-level composable, it wont be recomposed ever
@Composable
fun MyComposableScreen(
viewModel:MyVm,
launchActivity:()->Unit
){
  val someDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

  MyComposableContent()

  GenericErrorDialog(someDialog = someDialog)

  when (val state = viewModel.response.observeAsState().value) {
    // Query 1  
    is Content -> LaunchedEffect(Unit) { launchActivity() }
    Error -> {
      // Query 2
  // Gets called everytime this composable gets invalidated, for eg in case of TextField change, compiler is invalidating it.
 // But if i change it to LaunchedEffect(Unit), invalidation has no effect,LaunchedEffect only gets called when there is new update to the LiveData. why?
      SideEffect { someDialog.value = true}
    }
  }
}

// This is the content, which can be recomposed in case of email is changed
@Composable
fun MyComposableContent(
onEmailChange:(email) -> Unit,
email:String,
){
  TextField(
   email = email,
   onValueChange = onEmailChange
  )
}
```

I have doubts related to Query 1 and Query 2 both are part of top-level composable which will never be re-composed, but can be invalidated,

```
when (val state = viewModel.response.observeAsState().value) { // observing to live-data
        // Query 1  
        is Content -> LaunchedEffect(Unit) { launchActivity() }
        Error -> {
          // Query 2
          SideEffect { someDialog.value = true}
        }
      }
```

In case of is

```
Content -> LaunchedEffect(Unit) { launchActivity() }
```

I believe this should be fine as we want to launch an activity only when `LaunchedEffect` is part of the first time composition, and it will be only part of the composition if live data  state is Content

I faced issue in second scenario,

```
Error -> {
   // Query 2
  SideEffect { someDialog.value = true // shows a dialog} 
}
```

If last state of `live-data`, is Error in viewModel. And every time i make changes in the `TextField`  my top level `MyComposableScreen` was getting `invalidated`(not recomposed) by compose compiler, and since last state of live-data was set as error, `SideEffect` was running every time, which is fine as it should run for every successful composition and re-composition.

But, if i change it from `SideEffect` to `LaunchedEffect(Unit){someDialog.value = true}` dialog box was not showing up every time `MyComposableScreen` was `invalidated`, thats the desired behavior.

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit) gets called only if there live-data emits the new state again because of any UI-action.
```

But, I am not sure regarding the reasoning behind it,  why the code inside `LaunchedEffect(Unit){someDialog.value = true}` does not trigger after composable gets `invalidated` but the code inside `SideEffect` gets triggered after composable gets invalidated?

---

To make it more clear

I understand the difference

`SideEffect` -> on every successful composition and re-composition, if it's part of it
`LaunchedEffect` ->  when its enters composition and span across re-composition unless the keys are changed.

But in above scenario - this code particularly

```
@Composable
fun MyTopLevelComposable(viewModel:MyViewModel){

  when (val state = viewModel.response.observeAsState().value) { // observing live-data state
    is Content -> LaunchedEffect(Unit) { launchActivity() }
    Error -> SideEffect { someDialog.value = true}
  }
}
```

It will never get recomposed.  The only reason for this composable to be called again could be if compose compiler invalidates the view.

My Query is -> when view/composable gets invalidated

`SideEffect {someDialog.value = true}`  executes, because it will again go through composition  not re-composition  as viewModel.response(which is live-data) last state was `Error`

But if change it to `LaunchedEffect(Unit) {someDialog.value = true}`  it doesn't executes again after the composable is invalidated. It only reacts to a new state emitted by the `live-data.`

Question is why? Invalidate  should start composition again, and since it's a composition. not re-composition `LaunchedEffect`  should behave similarly to `SideEffect`  in this scenario, as both are reacting to `composition`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Compose, there is no such thing as invalidating a view.

When you keep your `when` in the same scope as the state variable, changing the state variable recomposes the contents of `when`, but when you move it to a separate composable, only updating `viewModel.response` can recompose it - Compose tries to reduce the number of views to recompose as much as possible.

`LaunchedEffect(Unit)` will be re-run in two cases:

1. If it was removed from the view tree during one of the previous recompositions and then added again. For example, if you wrap `LaunchedEffect` in `if` and the condition is first `false` and then `true`. Or, in your case, if `when` will choose `Error ->` after `is Content ->`, this will also remove `LaunchedEffect` from the view tree.
2. If one of the keys passed to `LaunchedEffect` has changed.

It looks like your problem is that `LaunchedEffect` does not restart when new content value come in, to solve this, you need to pass this value as `key` in `LaunchedEffect`, instead of `Unit`:

```
LaunchedEffect(state) { launchActivity() }
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. It's working fine, the way I want. Had few doubts. 
Earlier I was under the impression that, only the composable which is reading a parameter, gets recomposed based on the value on slot-table, and caller won't be affected. But after this post by zach https://dev.to/zachklipp/scoped-recomposition-jetpack-compose-what-happens-when-state-changes-l78 it cleared by understanding.

Comment: And i also thought, invalidation and recomposition are different things! wich is not true, they both are same in compose world as you mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Query regarding LaunchedEffect, it does not restart, which is fine, wanted to understand the reason behind it in this particular use-case.
Documentation says, LaunchedEffect if a constant key is passed, gets triggered only during first composition and same is spanned across recomposition, period.

Comment: In above use-case, if MyTopLevelComposable is scheculed for composition and when the composition happens, if state is Content, it will trigger LaunchedEffect - correct?

Again MyTopLevelComposable is recomposed, and if last state of viewModel.response.observeAsState().value was Content it's not triggering there LaunchedEffect, but it does if viewModel.response emits the Content state again?
Why?

Why recomposition is affecting the LaunchedEffect if it's supposed to be triggered only during first composition.

Comment: Or are you saying, as you have mentioned in your answer, any effect-handlers if removed from tree and added again, it will be be same as initial composition? As effect-handers life-cycle is dependent on it's enclosing composable lifecycle

Comment: LaunchedEffect does re-start when new Content Value comes in, it doesn't restart if the composable is recomposed because of some other state change and when block livedata, gives the cached response as earlier, which was Content.

Comment: LaunchedEffect -> If it was removed from the view tree during one of the previous recompositions and then added again - this answers my question.

Comment: IMO Documentation can be better, stating adding LaunchedEffect in the vie-tree is same as it's initial composition. I got confused thinking, when doc says initial composition, it meant the initial composition of enclosing composable, LaunchedEffect is added in.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect

Comment: @Ritt, the initial composition is when this particular code is executed. If `when` went the other way, the triggered effect was not executed.

Comment: So, everytime code gets executed (if/when) block - or say everytime LaunchedEffect removed and then added back again. 
It is initial composition - whenever it gets added?

Comment: @Ritt yes, it's initial composition of this particular view

Answer (score 5):

They just behave differently for a reason. Have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

For `LaunchEffect`, it only gets call the first time because you've specified `Unit` for its key. If you'd like it to trigger at a specific recomposition, use the state value you'd like to observe. Each time it changes, the `LaunchEffect` will be triggered.

Comment: Yes, I am aware if the effect-handlers difference. I have updated my question.